# Duplicate particular Structure on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

That's what I have:


HTML

```
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
  <table class="table-product">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        .........
        <td>
          <buttom class="btn-copy-link"></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="dont-copy-that-btn></button>
  <div class="collapse"></div>
</div>
```

jQ

```
init: function () {
      var that = this;

      this.$productEdit.on('click', '.btn-copy-link', function(){
          var $cTable = $(this).closest('.table-product'),
              $ele = $cTable.clone(true),
              $gName = $ele.find('td:first'),
              $lName = $ele.find('.product-link-title'),
              $idL = $ele.find('.product-link-id');

          $cTable.after($ele);
          $gName.empty();
          $lName.val($lName.val() + " Копия");
          $idL.val('');
        });
}
```

Current function copies the nearest `table` and inserts it after the original but i also need to copy the nearest `div` with class `collapse` and past `table` + `div` after that `collapse`. Copy `button` located in `table`.

Something like this:

```
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
  <table class="table-product">
    <button class="btn-copy-link"></button>
  </table>
  <button class="dont-copy-that-btn></button>
  <div class="collapse"></div>
</div>
```

after CLICK:

```
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
   <table class="table-product">
     <button class="btn-copy-link"></button>
   </table>
   <button class="dont-copy-that-btn></button>
   <div class="collapse"></div>
   <!-- COPY-->
   <table class="table-product">
     <button class="btn-copy-link"></button>
   </table>
   <div class="collapse"></div>
 </div>
```

If user click `button` again in a first pair of `table` + `div` it duplicate them after that pair. If we click `button` in a second pair - got copy after second one etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next()` from the closest table element to find the `div` you need. Try this:

```
this.$productEdit.on('click', '.btn-copy-link', function(){
    var $cTable = $(this).closest('.table-product'),
        $div = $cTable.next('div.collapsed'),
        $ele = $cTable.clone(true);

    $ele.find('td:first').empty();
    $ele.find('.product-link-title').val($lName.val() + ' Копия');
    $ele.find('.product-link-id').val('');

    $div.after($ele); // insert table clone after previous div
    $ele.after($div.clone(true)); // append cloned div after new table clone
});
```

Comment: Thx, ur code works but have a little problem. Between the first pair there is another btn, we dont need to copy it but that btn ruin ur $cTable.next('div.collapsed').

Comment: Try `nextAll('div.collapsed:first')`. If that doesn't work, please update the HTML in your question to match what you actually have